# Build TensorFlow from the source

Tags: exception, build, tensorflow, bazel

In the `./configure` stage, after setting all the options by default, the terminal threw me this error:

As you required, here's the full outputs:

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /home/jingw222/anaconda3/bin/python]: 
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] 
jemalloc enabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] 
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] 
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] 
No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages]

Using python library path: /home/jingw222/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] 
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] 
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Configuration finished
Extracting Bazel installation...
..................

unexpected pipe read status: (error: 2): No such file or directory
Server presumed dead. Now printing '/home/jingw222/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jingw222/ada033fd33c06190d78b77ab4907f1d0/server/jvm.out':
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeExecutor.skyFunctions(SkyframeExecutor.java:348)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeExecutor.init(SkyframeExecutor.java:586)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.init(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:252)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:211)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutor.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutor.java:162)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SequencedSkyframeExecutorFactory.create(SequencedSkyframeExecutorFactory.java:48)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.WorkspaceBuilder.build(WorkspaceBuilder.java:81)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.initWorkspace(BlazeRuntime.java:204)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.newRuntime(BlazeRuntime.java:1023)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.createBlazeRPCServer(BlazeRuntime.java:850)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.serverMain(BlazeRuntime.java:789)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeRuntime.main(BlazeRuntime.java:570)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.bazel.BazelMain.main(BazelMain.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.lang.management.UnixExtendedOperatingSystem incompatible with com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.ResourceUsage.<clinit>(ResourceUsage.java:45)
    ... 13 more
```

So, basically, most of them are not enabled by default. How to approach problems like this?

Comment: In which platform are you trying to build?

Comment: It's actually Ubuntu 16.04. However, I just managed to get through by setting every option by default. And yet another issue pops up. :(

Comment: Can you paste the full output of the `./configure` step (like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#configure_the_installation))? I think you may not have some of the required things installed, and so the "defaults" may be invalid.

Comment: Just updated the post. Was it something to do with `Bazel`? But neither the stable version nor testing one seemed to be working.

Comment: If you haven't already, you can try to run `bazel clean --expunge` and repeat; maybe the build tree was left in some invalid state after the first failed configuration.

Comment: That command gave me this: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:141)
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:130).....

Comment: Well that's messed up. Take a look at the (quite) recent activity in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8092), it seems like a similar problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove `~/.cache/bazel`?

Comment: Removed it, and sadly nothing changed. The error happened again.

Comment: @jdhesa I installed Bazel by the instruction exactly. The java (and other dependencies) were automatically installed though. Is there any java component that I missed out?

Comment: Turned out it was JDK. Come on, I simply chose the recommended first option to install Bazel after all. Thanks you for you guys help. :)

Comment: As in, a JDK version issue? Would you mind putting together a short description of the setup which produced the error and the one that worked in an answer?

Comment: Not even a version issue. It's a no-brainer. I didn't have JDK installed in my machine. And when I install Bazel using the first option, somehow it installed some java dependencies except for JDK listed on the second installing option. With JDK having been installed, I immediately made the error message go away.

Answer (score 1):

Install jdk 8 manually:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

After that build again. 
Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8092) issue for more info.